# Read xml data with same tags using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read XML data with same tags, but I am not able to get all the data.

Sample XML code:

```
<print_set>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">-------------------------------</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">MARRY BROWN FAMILY RESTAURANT</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">Anna Nagar East</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">AH 45, 4th Avenue</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">5000023</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">Shanthi Colony</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">Chennai</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">For Home Delivery : 46218777</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">OrderOnline:marrybrownindia.com</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">-------------------------------</line>
    <line align="left" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">Employee:vinod</line>
    <line align="left" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">Bill Number:Ma-70</line>
    <line align="left" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">Date:26/07/2014    Time:12:14 PM</line>
    <line align="center" weight="normal" font="Courier New" height="20">-------------------------------</line>
</print_set>
```

And the code that I use to read it:

```
XmlNodeList xnListCommon = xml.SelectNodes("/print_set");

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnListCommon)
{
    company_name = xn["line"].InnerText;
    font_style = xn["line"].Attributes["font"].Value;
    weight = xn["line"].Attributes["weight"].Value;
    alignment = xn["line"].Attributes["align"].Value;
    height = Convert.ToInt32(xn["line"].Attributes["height"].Value);
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: So, what data are you not able to get?

Comment: If I Pass tag name line and i am getting only first value but. and then  it is coming out of the loop

Comment: I want to get the xml data with out passing the tag name even though my tags are same .

Comment: @MDFayaz what is the final result you want to get from this xml? Keep in mind, that after your current loop you will have only values of last line

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ-to-XML, it's fairly simple, using [Descendants()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From a path, use [Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path-to-file");
```

or, from an existing XML string, use [Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse("your XML string");
```

Then, to get the lines in the XML:

```
var lines = doc.Root.Descendants("line");
```

You can leave the element name out, if necessary. I'm not sure what exactly you're doing, but your loop would look something like this:

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    company_name = line.Value;
    font_style = line.XAttribute("font").Value;
    weight = line.XAttribute("weight").Value;
    alignment = line.XAttribute("align").Value;
    height = Convert.ToInt32(line.XAttribute("height").Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks but  I want my code to run in  2.0 also but 2.0 will not support linq

Comment: @MDFayaz You might want to include that in your question.

Comment: I am storing xml data in a string and passing that string to method then it is showing Illegal characters in path exception

Comment: Probably because you ignored the words "path-to-file" given in the example; that particular XDocument method wants a path, not XML content. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much i got the result now